# Real time slider input sum and show on a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

He guys
I have been trying to create 4 range sliders with value showing in the right and showing their sum on real time.

What I was able to do-

1. I created the 4 range slider
2. I showed their value upon sliding
3. I have some code to sum them.

What I am not being able to do

1. I can't show the sum in real time.

See the snap bellow:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div id="slider">
<form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value; 
               amount2.value=rangeInput2.value;
               amount3.value=rangeInput3.value;
               amount4.value=rangeInput4.value;  
            " >

    <input name="one"     class="bar" type="range" id="rangeInput" value="0" onchange="rangevalue.value=value"/>
    <input name="two" class="bar" type="range" id="rangeInput2" value="0" onchange="rangevalue2.value=value"/>
    <input name="three" class="bar" type="range" id="rangeInput3" value="0" onchange="rangevalue3.value=value"/>
    <input name="four" class="bar" type="range" id="rangeInput4" value="0" onchange="rangevalue4.value=value"/>
    <span  class="highlight"></span>

     <output name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
     <output name="amount2" for="rangeInput2">0</output>
     <output name="amount3" for="rangeInput3">0</output>
     <output name="amount4" for="rangeInput4">0</output>

    <br/>

Total:  <div id="total"></div>

     </form>
</div>


     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#total").click(function(){
                var sum=$("#rangevalue").val()+$("#rangevalue2").val()+$("#rangevalue3").val()+$("#rangevalue4").val();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Any help on how to show the summation data in real time? So the sum changes when I move sliders?

Thanks.

Comment: `click` is going to happen when you *click* `#target`; I think you want to use `change`: `$('input.bar[type=range]').on('input', function(){})`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already using jQuery so remove the inline event handlers and use jQuery instead.

There doesn't seem to any `rangevalue` elements in the HTML, they are called `rangeInput` ?

The event for continuous updates on a range slider is the `oninput` event.

Then it's just a matter of parsing to numbers and adding up.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bar').on('input', function () {
        var val1 = parseInt($("#rangeInput").val(), 10);
        var val2 = parseInt($("#rangeInput2").val(), 10);
        var val3 = parseInt($("#rangeInput3").val(), 10);
        var val4 = parseInt($("#rangeInput4").val(), 10);

        var sum =  val1 + val2 + val3 + val4;
        $('#total').text(sum)
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/sfgjgh0L/)

Comment: Worked like a charm. I was too stupid, I forgot to include Jquery library.